# Date object not behaving as expected

Tags: javascript, date, datetime

I have a control that shows the current month and year at the start of my application. It has 2 buttons that will add or subtract 1 from the current month. I use the same function to add/subtract to initialize the date by calling it with 0. Here is the function:

```
$scope.SetDateMonth = function (modifier) {
        if (modifier === 0) {
            //initialize the current date, only called on load
            $scope.CurrentDate = new Date();

        } else {
            //alter the currentdate
            $scope.CurrentDate.setMonth($scope.CurrentDate.getMonth() + modifier);
        }
        /*
        $scope.StartOfRange = new Date($scope.CurrentDate.getFullYear(), $scope.CurrentDate.getMonth());
        alert($scope.StartOfRange.getDate());
        $scope.StartOfRange.setDate(1);
        alert($scope.StartOfRange.getDate());
        //$scope.StartOfRange.setDate(1);
        $scope.EndOfRange = new Date($scope.CurrentDate.getFullYear(), $scope.CurrentDate.getMonth()+1);
        $scope.EndOfRange.setDate($scope.EndOfRange.getDate() - 1);
       */

        //set startofrange to first day of month
        $scope.StartOfRange = new Date($scope.CurrentDate.getFullYear(), $scope.CurrentDate.getMonth(), 1);
        //this sets the date to the last day of the previous month. Bc. we add 1 to the month, this will result in the last day of CurrentMonth
        $scope.StartOfRange = new Date($scope.CurrentDate.getFullYear(), $scope.CurrentDate.getMonth()+1, 0); 

        console.log("Start");
        console.log($scope.StartOfRange);
        console.log("End");
        console.log($scope.EndOfRange);

        //.setHours(0,0,0,0)

        //$scope.DateChanged();
    }
```

I want to add 2 global variables to this. Start/EndOfRange. They have to store the first and last day of the month. You can see that quite a bit of code has been commented out, I've been trying a lot of diffrent examples I found online. I'm stuck on the setDate() (maybe its not in the code I provided anymore, I did try to use it but couldn't get it to work) function. If I call it with param 1, it sets the date to 30. I've tried UTC times aswell.

The odd thing is that when I use an alert, it shows 1 as supposed. When I use console.log, it does not. I tried all values from 1 to 30, they all give vague unexpected results.

Reading from w3 (https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_obj_date.asp) I'm calling it correctly. I did manage to get the correct date out of it by constructing a new date object with day(or date, bit confusing, 3rd parameter) set to -29. Seems to consistently set the date to 1 but deffinitly not a long term solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using this code:

```
$scope.SetDateMonth = function (modifier) {
        if (modifier === 0) {
            //initialize the current date, only called on load
            $scope.CurrentDate = new Date();

        } else {
            //alter the currentdate
            $scope.CurrentDate.setMonth($scope.CurrentDate.getMonth() + modifier);
        }

        //set startofrange to first day of month
        $scope.StartOfRange = new Date($scope.CurrentDate.getFullYear(), $scope.CurrentDate.getMonth(), 1);
        //this sets the date to the last day of the previous month. Bc. we add 1 to the month, this will result in the last day of CurrentMonth
        $scope.EndOfRange = new Date($scope.CurrentDate.getFullYear(), $scope.CurrentDate.getMonth()+1, 0); 
        console.log("Start");
        console.log($scope.StartOfRange);
        console.log("End");
        console.log($scope.EndOfRange);
   }
```

Checking the console output in both firefox and internet explorer. Since the current date is 4-5-2017, StartOfRange should be 1-5-2017, EndOfRange should be 31-5-2017.

FireFox:

```
Start
Date 2017-04-30T22:00:00.000Z
End
Date 2017-05-30T22:00:00.000Z
```

IE:

```
Start
[date] Mon May 01 2017 00:00:00 GMT+0200
End
[date] Wed May 31 2017 00:00:00 GMT+0200
```

Will edit if I get firefox working with the same code.

edit 1:
added this code:

```
var test = $scope.CurrentDate;
test.setDate(1);
console.log("test:");
console.log(test);
```

This works as expected for some reason. However, it doesn't only set test's date, because its a reference to CurrentDate. I don't see why this would work but setting date to 1 in the constructor wouldn't..

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following two functions to find the first day and last day of the current month.

```
$scope.StartOfRange = $scope.getFirstDay();    
$scope.EndOfRange = $scope.getLastDay();
$scope.getFirstDay = function ()
{
    var currDate = new Date();     
    year = currDate.getFullYear();
    month = currDate.getMonth();
    day = currDate.getDate();
    var lastMonth = month - 1;
    if (month == 0) {
        year--;
        lastMonth = 11;
    }
    lastDay = 28;
    var previousMonthDate = new Date(year, lastMonth,lastDay);

    while (previousMonthDate < currDate)
    {
        previousMonthDate = new Date(year, lastMonth, lastDay++);
        var curMonth = previousMonthDate.getMonth();
        if (curMonth == month)
        {
            console.log("First Day :" + previousMonthDate);
            return previousMonthDate;
        }
    }
}
$scope.getLastDay = function () {
    var currDate = new Date();
    year = currDate.getFullYear();
    var nextYear = year;
    month = currDate.getMonth();
    day = currDate.getDate();
    var nextMonth = month + 1;
    if (month == 11) {
        nextYear++;
        nextMonth = 0;
    }
    lastDay = 28;
    var currentMonthDate = new Date(year, month, lastDay);
    var nextMonthDate = new Date(nextYear, nextMonth, 1);
    while (currentMonthDate < nextMonthDate) {
        var finalDate = currentMonthDate;
        currentMonthDate = new Date(year, month, lastDay++);
        var curMonth = currentMonthDate.getMonth();
        if (curMonth == nextMonth) {
            console.log("LastDay :" + finalDate);
            return finalDate;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This wouldn't work as my CurrentDate is only set to now() on page load. When  I modify the current mont, Start/EndOfRange would then still return the first/last day of now(). Besides using hardcoded numbers is the current implementation (if month == 11). I want to use the Date object for these calculations. The problem remains: if I call setDate(1), the date prints as 30 on the console.

Comment: Why do you want to use now() for current date on page load? and why do you want to call setDate(1) ? You want to have the first and last day of the current month right?

Comment: Have you tried implementing this code? I have tested it and this should work. Try implementing this and post the error you are getting if any.

Comment: I'm sure it won't give any errors. I'm also sure its not what Im looking for.

Comment: What exactly you need? Can you pls be more specific?

Comment: I included a reference page from w3. Im using setDate(1). Its setting the date to 30 when I read it from the console. I'm wondering why it behaves that way. I don't want to calculate things like if Im in the last month, add a year. All of that intelligence is already in the Date object. I need to learn how to use it correctly.

Comment: I have checked this setDate(1) and its working fine for me! Can you share your updated code with what exactly you have tried and what you got without any comments? and also you have used StartOfRange twice in your current code instead of EndOfRange

Comment: in your code: var nextMonthDate = new Date(nextYear, nextMonth, 1);

Comment: for me it sets the date to 30. Either my browser is drunk or my timezone settings are weird. I can't figure out why it does this.